# Angular + ngClass not applied outside of ngView

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have an app with 2 controllers.

http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/UDf2m/4/

You see that I apply a boolean value to the scope. Depending on that variable I want to apply a class with ng-class. But that does not work outside of ngview.

**This works not:**

```
<div ng-class="{'red': isRed}" >
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**This works:**

```
<div>
  <div ng-class="{'red': isRed}" ng-view></div>
</div>
```

It works when I apply the variable to the rootScope.
I can also get it to work when I make isRed a function but, then this function gets called on every click multiple times which I suspect to cause performance problems in a bigger application.

How can I get ngclass to be evaluated correctly outside of ngview?

### Update:

I am collecting here the possible solutions:

#### Rootscope

As mentioned before and by [Franci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469534/franci) applying the state to the rootscope works: http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/UDf2m/9/

*Disadvantage:* Pollutes the rootScope

#### Function

Make it a function call. http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/UDf2m/12/

*Disadvantage*: The function gets called very, very often (4 times in this small example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controllers scope is only available inside the ui-view element. Outside the ui-view only $rootScope is available. What you can do if your application really requires this kind of structure is inject the $rootScope and add the isRed property to it. You have the $rootScope already commented out in your code which should make it work.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
    console.log('MyCtrl');

    /*
    $rootScope.isRed = function() {
        console.log('isRed');
        return angular.isDefined($routeParams.resource);
    };
    */

    $rootScope.isRed = angular.isDefined($routeParams.resource);
    //$rootScope.isRed = true;
    $scope.resource = $routeParams.resource;
});
```

Comment: This makes `isRed=true` only when MyCtrl is loaded using the link.

Comment: I understand but you still can't access MyCtrl scope outside of the ng-view element, so the only way to have it available globaly is to add the method to the $rootScope. I've done that in the code above but I left it commented out. This is not good practice but it's the only way for you to be able to communicate to an outside scope from within the controller.

Comment: Yeah that's true . But you could also add a controller to outside of the ng-view as in my answer as well. That won't break any best practice. :)

Comment: Going by your example, you're adding controller when routing and not in your HTML. In case you might want to use resolve to load data when routing you want to keep it that way. You might have problems later down the road if you declare the controller on your HTML element that you want to be tied to a specific route. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, because it is the easiest to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ng-controller` for root level

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/some">A resource</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/some/arbitrary/url">A deep linked resource</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-class="{'red': isRed}" >
         <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UDf2m/8/) it works fine

Comment: you do NOT need to re-bind ng-app, assuming that it is already bound (which we will since angular is doing things.)

Comment: @sxnine , yeah I missed it.

Comment: @Jayantha I am sorry, but that does not work as expected. The class is always applied. The correct behaviour is as in that fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/UDf2m/9/ The problem with this fiddle is the rootScope, which I don't want to pollute.

Comment: The really odd behaviour I am seeing is like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/UDf2m/10/ isRed evaluates to the correct value, but the class is not applied because it gets evaluated afterwards.

Comment: Ah OK. I think http://jsfiddle.net/UDf2m/15/ this is what you expected. I have added another controller for the parent level of your controllers to handle the class. Hope it helps..

Comment: Now you are using the function approach I described earlier. Probably there is no way around these two options.